# How to get the index of Arrays.stream(array).min()?

Tags: java, arrays, java-stream

I want to get the index of min, I tried ways like getIndexOf etc. but none of them worked. How can I do this?

```
import java.util.Arrays;
class getIndexOfMin {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double arr[] = {263.5, 393.75, 5.0, 289.75};

        double min = Arrays.stream(arr).min().getAsDouble();
        
        System.out.println(min);
    }
}
```

Comment: As a side note, a stream is slightly slower than simply looping through an array. We use streams to make the code more readable, but in your case it wouldn't be more readable (because the operation you want to do is not standard) and at the same time you should loop twice on the array while you could get the job done simply looping once through the array with a classic for loop

Answer (score 4):

You can make a stream of the indices of the array instead, from 0 to `arr.length` (exclusive):

```
Optional<Integer> minIndex = IntStream.range(0, arr.length).boxed()
    .min(Comparator.comparingDouble(i -> arr[i]));
```

Note that this is an optional, as the array could be empty. Also, when there are multiple minimums, it is not specified which one's index it will return. In the implementation that I'm using (OpenJDK 17), it returns the first one's index.

If you want to control which minimum's index you get, you can do:

```
Optional<Integer> minIndex = IntStream.range(0, arr.length).boxed().reduce(
    // gets the first one's:
    (a, b) -> arr[a] <= arr[b] ? a : b
    // gets the last one's:
    // (a, b) -> arr[a] < arr[b] ? a : b
);
```

Comment: You can make it a little more efficient with `comparingDouble()`.

Comment: *when there are multiple minimums, it will return the index of the first one.* Is this specified somewhere?

Comment: @shmosel No... My brain jumped a few steps when making that conclusion.

Answer (score 2):

```
int index;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    double d = arr[i];
    if (d == min){
       index = i; 
       break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how it can be done without iterating over the array indices and trying to mimic `for`-loop with a stream.

And we can also grab the actual minimal value along the way.

For that we can use [`DoubleStream.collect()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html#collect(java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.function.ObjDoubleConsumer,java.util.function.BiConsumer)) which expects three arguments:

- `Supplier<R>` *supplier* - provides a mutable object which would serve as a container of data;
- `ObjDoubleConsumer<R>` *accumulator* - determines how stream elements should be accumulated in the mutable collector provided by the *supplier*;
- `BiConsumer<R,R>` *combiner* - combines partial results while executing the stream in parallel.

As a mutable container which should be provided by the supplier we can use an array `double[]` (*if you have a look at the source code of Collectors that are intended to accumulate primitive values, namely* `summingInt()`, `summingDouble()`, etc. *you would probably find some similarities*).

```
double[] arr = {263.5, 393.75, 5.0, 289.75};
        
double[] min = Arrays.stream(arr)
    .collect(
        () -> new double[]{0, -1, 0},    // supplier
        (double[] res, double next) -> { // accumulator
            res[2]++; // element count
            if (res[1] == -1 || res[0] > next) {
                res[0] = next;          // min value
                res[1] = res[2] - 1;    // corresponding index (element count - 1)
            }
        },
        (left, right) -> {              // combiner
            if (left[0] > right[0]) {
                left[0] = right[0];
                left[1] = left[2] + right[1];
            }
            left[2] += right[2];
        }
    );
        
System.out.printf("Min value is %s at index: %d", min[0], (int) min[1]);
```

*Output:*

```
Min value is 5.0 at index: 2
```

The logic for determining the min value and tracking the number of consumed elements shown above can be encapsulated into a `class` (as suggested by *@Holger*) which would be used as the accumulation type instread of array.

For convenience, I've implemented [`DoubleConsumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/DoubleConsumer.html) interface, its method `accept()` would be used to implement *accumulator*. And method `merge()` would be used in the *combiner*.

```
public static class MinValueAndIndex implements DoubleConsumer {
    private int totalCount;
    private int index;
    private double min;

    @Override
    public void accept(double value) {
        if (totalCount == 0 || value < min) {
            min = value;
            index = totalCount;
        }
        totalCount++;
    }
    
    public void merge(MinValueAndIndex other) {
        if (min > other.min) {
            min = other.min;
            index = totalCount + other.index;
        }
        totalCount += other.totalCount;
    }
    
    // getters
}
```

The stream would look like that:

```
double[] arr = {263.5, 393.75, 5.0, 289.75};
        
MinValueAndIndex valueIndex = Arrays.stream(arr)
    .collect(
        MinValueAndIndex::new,
        MinValueAndIndex::accept,
        MinValueAndIndex::merge
    );
    
System.out.printf("Min value is %s at index: %d", valueIndex.getMin(), valueIndex.getIndex());
```

*Output:*

```
Min value is 5.0 at index: 2
```

Comment: Additionally (well, this is just my opinion, others might disagree), this kind of reduction in particular is almost unreadable. A solution with intermediate object and `IntStream` mimicking the for loop will be much cleaner, more readable and less error prone.

Comment: @Chaosfire This task of finding the index using a stream has no practical value, and can be useful only as an exercise that allows to get familiar with the API. And I think this code demonstrates the capabilities of the API well, and it's **not** easy to grasp (I didn't tell the opposite). BTW, does [this](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/stream/Collectors.java#l516) resemble you something? I think mimicking a `for`-loop is **harmful** while learning, unless the learner doesn't want to develop a bad habit.

Comment: You have a point, but a new learner will have a very hard time figuring out what does this code do. If the point is to get familiar with the Stream API capabilities, the simpler, the better. Also at least in java 17, this does not work with parallel streams (and that's where streams really shine), i get a wrong index with parallel execution.

Comment: @Chaosfire Fixed. Source array is too, spliterator was feed only one element to every thread, for that reason accumulated index remained to be zero.

Comment: @Chaosfire Yes, simple things are great because they allow speed up the learning process, but challenges are inevitable (*and even necessary*) if one wants to learn something in depth, none can eat only candies. I disagree with your initial phrase about cleanness, there's nothing "clean" in iterating over array's indices with a stream, in such case *clean-coding recipe:* **don't mimic `for`-loop, use `for`-loop**. Too many beginners have a misconception that streams are just a fancy way of writing loops, it's important to emphasize that they belong to different worlds and don't match 1:1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom class to hold together an index and the value at this index. The task to find the index with min value becomes trivial then, and you can find the index and value all at once.

A record is perfect for this purpose, if you use version before java 14, you can just use normal class.

```
public record IndexValue(int index, double value) {
}
```

Example usage:

```
public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[] arr = {263.5, 393.75, 5.0, 289.75};
    IndexValue min = IntStream.range(0, arr.length) //stream indexes
            .mapToObj(i -> new IndexValue(i, arr[i])) //map index and value together using the class
            .min(Comparator.comparing(IndexValue::value)) //find minimum by comparing values
            .orElseGet(() -> new IndexValue(-1, Double.MAX_VALUE)); //supply default value suiting your needs, if array was empty
    System.out.println("Min index value - " + min);
  }
}
```

Prints - `Min index value - IndexValue[index=2, value=5.0]`. All operations in this stream are non-interfering and stateless, and it's safe for parallel execution.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following solution should be preferred, as in 1 iteration of the stream you collect both the required index and the required value.

```
double arr[] = {263.5, 393.75, 5.0, 289.75};

Optional<Map.Entry<Integer, Double>> keyValueOpt = IntStream.range(0, arr.length)
              .mapToObj(i -> Map.entry(i,arr[i]))
              .min(Map.Entry.comparingByValue());

keyValueOpt.ifPresent(keyValue -> System.out.println(String.format("Index %s with min value %s", keyValue.getKey(), keyValue.getValue())));
```

[image]

You also don't need any new classes to be introduced to your code as the `Map.Entry(K k, V v)` fits the role of keeping a single pair of Key, Value to your result.